# How to switch Youtube-dl cookies files?

Tags: caching, cookies, instagram, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download video from instagram with simple command

```
youtube-dl https://instagram.com/p/<ID>
```

It doesn't work properly for me because i'm using my Netherlands VPN (Intsagram wants me to log in).
I logged in my ig account and generated a cookies file to use it with youtube-dl and it works fine! But, if i want to switch my ig account and use another one cookies file from another account it returns and error.

I found out that youtube-dl rewriting my cookies file after first request. The difference between this 2 cookies files in session_id cookie.

So, maybe somebody knows how could i change my accounts?

Comment: Stucked on the same thing

Comment: have you tried replacing content in cookie file with your new logged in account cookie? I mean try with same file but different content